# Bash or systemd method to run shell script continuously after current task is finished

Tags: linux, bash, shell, networking

I'm using a program to scan huge IP segment (/8 IP address) and save the output in Linux directory.

To run the program, I'm writing a script namely **scan.sh** that look like this

```
#!/bin/sh
while IFS= read -r IP || [[ -N "$IP" ]]; do
    /path/to/program $IP > /output/path/$IP.xml;
done < ip.txt
```

Since the IP address is so huge, it is not feasible to fit all IP in one file so I split it by chunk and 
run the script concurrently like this. Let's name this **allscan.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
/path/script/0-4/scan.sh & /path/script/5-10/scan.sh /path/script/11-15/scan.sh
```

Obviously, the script includes codes that's much longer than above but you get the idea. 0-4, 5-10 folder representing ip address that split into small chunk.

During first run, it took 28 days to finish.

My question is how to keep it running continuously once current task is finished?

I don't think monthly cronjob is suitable for this because if the task took more than 30 days to finish it will rerun the script and create unnecessary load to the server.

Comment: What exactly should be running continuously? What is current task? If you don't have all ips in one file, why not just do `cat ip0-4.txt ip5-10.txt ip11-15.txt | while read .....` if you do the same with each file? The "iterating over ips" part really looks like a job for `xargs` that also can run processes in paralell.. If you mentioned systemd, I would use a systemd service file for a job that takes 28 days to complete.

Comment: Hi - I need to continuously re-execute allscan.sh when it finishes. Thanks for the 'cat' suggestion, I will consider using it.

Comment: Why not then just `while true; do allscan.sh; done`?